# Disabling button using setState inside component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

After a button is clicked inside `RecipeListItem` component and function handleFavorites has stared I want my button to be ***DISABLED***.

What is wrong with my logic? Because this code dosen't work...

Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addToFavorites } from '../../actions/';
import './style.css';

import Ingredients from '../../components/Ingredients';

class RecipeListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      valueButton: false,
    };
  }

  thumbnailCheck(link) {
    if (link.length === 0) {
      // Thumbnail placeholder
      const newLink =
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/dfe57evk4/image/upload/v1506802313/no_thumb_hxdh5h.png';
      return newLink;
    }
    return link;
  }

  handleFavorites(fav) {
    this.setState({ valueButton: true });
    this.props.addToFavorites(fav);
  }

  render() {
    const { title, link, ingredients, thumbnail } = this.props;
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item">
        <img
          className="RecipeListItem-img"
          src={this.thumbnailCheck(thumbnail)}
          alt="thumbnail"
        />
        <a href={link} target="_blank">
          <span className="RecipeListItem-title">{title}</span>
        </a>
        <button
          disabled={this.state.valueButton}
          className="RecipeListItem-fav-button btn btn-secondary"
          onClick={() => this.handleFavorites([title, link])}
        >
          + Add to Fav
        </button>
        <br />
        <a href={link} target="_blank">
          <span className="RecipeListItem-full-link">Full recipe link</span>
        </a>
        <br />
        <span className="RecipeListItem-ingredients-header">Ingredients:</span>
        <Ingredients ingredients={ingredients} />
        <br />
      </li>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ addToFavorites }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(RecipeListItem);
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import RecipeListItem from '../../containers/RecipeListItem';

class RecipeList extends Component {
  render() {
    const recipesList = this.props.recipesReady.map(oneRecipe => {
      const key = _.uniqueId('recipe_');
      return (
        <RecipeListItem
          key={key}
          title={oneRecipe.recipe.label}
          link={oneRecipe.recipe.url}
          ingredients={oneRecipe.recipe.ingredients}
          thumbnail={oneRecipe.recipe.image}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-xl-center">
          <ul className="col-xl-12">{recipesList}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

---

EDIT:
I'm thinking... maybe after that button is clicked this component is re-renderd with `valueButton: false`, maybe that is the cause?

--- More details

So the button looks normal it is clickable.

Only when I change manually

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      valueButton: true,
    };
  }
```

I have what I want -> disabled button which isn't clickable and it is grey, and mouse pointer isn't mouse anymore it is all inside bootstrap `btn btn-secondary`

So that code does not change state inside component, but still don't know why...

Comment: Could you be a little more specific when you say "doesn't work"? Is the button still clickable? Should it look differently? etc.

Comment: @MountainConqueror Code looks good. Should work. Maybe what you are missing is this `type="button"`. Just maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what's happening here. When the `addToFavorites` action is dispatched, the app runs a re-render, and the `key` you give to each `RecipeListItem` should prevent the internal state from being rewritten. However, the key is being generated wrongly. Essentially, a new key is being created *every time* the list is made.

Keys in React are meant to be traced back to the items that represent the elements being rendered. Here, the code is generating new random keys every time the elements are rendered, which is basically the same as using no key at all.

My suggestion: when fetching/creating the recipes, create the keys then and put them on the recipe objects, then do `key={oneRecipe.recipe.key}` in your map call when creating the `RecipeListItem` elements. Though here it looks like you might not need to create a unique key at all; the `url` property should suffice.

Comment: So worked like a charm! You are very clever, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You have to bind your `handleFavorites(fav)` to use `this` inside of it

```
class RecipeListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      valueButton: false,
    };
    this.handleFavorites = this.handleFavorites.bind(this);
  }

 // rest...
```

Comment: No, when I use `() => this.handleFavorites([title, link])` I don't have to do it, this function works, by the way, beacuse it calls `this.props.addToFavorites(fav);`